# trying to compile stir library: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’

Tags: c++, constants

First, I'm pretty new to C++ and C so be easy on me :-) 
Second, I know this question has be asked many times in many forms before, but I could figure
how to bend the answers to my case ...

I am trying to compile a file called utilities.cxx from the STIL library which has some kind of and "open source" license (not really LGPL and so I don't know if I can put here significant parts of it...

The code has the following function in it:

```
char *replace_extension(char *file_in_directory_name, 
            const char * const extension)
{
char * location_of_dot = 
strchr(find_filename(file_in_directory_name),'.');
// first truncate at extension
if (location_of_dot!= NULL)
*(location_of_dot) = '\0';

strcat (file_in_directory_name,extension);
return file_in_directory_name;
}
```

Compiling it gives the error:

```
g++  -O3  -ffast-math -DNDEBUG  -Wall -Wno-deprecated -I../lmf_v2.0
/includes -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -I./include  -DSTIR_SIMPLE_BITMAPS -DSC_XWINDOWS 
-o  opt/buildblock/utilities.o -MMD -MP -c buildblock/utilities.cxx 
buildblock/utilities.cxx: In function ‘char* stir::replace_extension(char*, const 
char*)’:
buildblock/utilities.cxx:225: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
make: *** [opt/buildblock/utilities.o] Error 1
```

Any help would be appreciated ... Thanks,

Oz

Ok, first part already answered ... here is the function which causes the second error:

```
const char * const 
find_filename(const char * const filename_with_directory)
{
const char * name;

#if defined(__OS_VAX__)
name = strrchr(filename_with_directory,']');
if (name==NULL)
name = strrchr(filename_with_directory,':');
#elif defined(__OS_WIN__)
name = strrchr(filename_with_directory,'\\');
if (name==NULL)
name = strrchr(filename_with_directory,'/');
if (name==NULL)
name = strrchr(filename_with_directory,':');
#elif defined(__OS_MAC__)
name = strrchr(filename_with_directory,':');
#else // defined(__OS_UNIX__)
name = strrchr(filename_with_directory,'/');
#endif 
if (name!=NULL)
// KT 10/01/2000 name++ changed to name+1
return name+1;
else
return filename_with_directory;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is causing the error:

```
char * location_of_dot = 
    strchr(find_filename(file_in_directory_name),'.');
```

[`strchr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/) returns a `const char*`, not a `char*` when called with a `const char*` as the first argument (I'm assuming `find_filename()` returns a `const char *`, otherwise you wouldn't be seeing this error).

Since you want to assign to the memory location returned by `strchr`, you don't want to use this overloaded version. Change `find_filename()` to return a `char*`.

**UPDATE:** You've since posted the code for `find_filename()` and changing the return type would involve changing other stuff (and doesn't make much sense besides). Instead, cast either the return value of `find_filename()` to a `char*` or cast the result of `strchr()` to a `char*`.

Example (uses a [const cast](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/const_cast)):

```
char * location_of_dot = const_cast<char*>(
    strchr(find_filename(file_in_directory_name),'.'));
```

Comment: Not according to the standard.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Check out [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/). It's overloaded to return `const char*` when the first argument is `const char*` instead of `char*`

Comment: What manual are ... reading? `man strchr` says `char * strchr(const char *s, int c);`

Comment: Hi Cameron , Thanks a bunch for the quick reply. But this code also does not compile, it raises another error ... g++  -O3  -ffast-math -DNDEBUG  -Wall -Wno-deprecated -I../lmf_v2.0/includes -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -I./include  -DSTIR_SIMPLE_BITMAPS -DSC_XWINDOWS -o opt/buildblock/utilities.o -MMD -MP -c buildblock/utilities.cxx 
buildblock/utilities.cxx: In function ‘char* stir::replace_extension(char*, const char*)’:
buildblock/utilities.cxx:228: error: assignment of read-only location ‘* location_of_dot’
make: *** [opt/buildblock/utilities.o] Error 1

Comment: Whoops, sorry, my bad, I didn't notice the C++ tag. Yes, strchr returns `const char*`.

Comment: The code won't compile fine then because of `*(location_of_dot) = '\0';` - you'd need to change `find_filename`.

Comment: @etarion: You're right. @Oz123: That's why you're getting that new compile error. I'll edit my answer shortly.

Comment: @ etarion, Camron, I just put that function there

Comment: Ok, learn something new every day ... Won't just qualifying it as `::strchr` solve the issue?

Comment: @Cameron, you mean instead of "const char * const 
find_filename(const char * const filename_with_directory)" to write "char *  
find_filename(const char * const filename_with_directory)"

Comment: @Oz123: Yes, except that now you've posted that function I can see that that would actually cause a compile error... editing again :-)

Comment: @Cameron, I know I would sound like an idiot, but there so many trees now, I can't see the forest ...

Comment: @Cameron, Thanks, I added your correction, now it compiles ! (With the code of find_filename(const char * const filename_with_directory)
unmodified. Besides that, I have other bugs in the code, which makes me remember why i hate "OpenSource" projects which have no repositories ... damn you STIR developers...

Answer (score 0):

add the following overload:

```
char* find_filename( char* filename_with_directory)
{
    char const* const fname = filename_with_directory;
    return const_cast<char*>( find_filename( fname ) );
}
```

disclaimer: code untouched by compiler's hands

cheers & hth.,